# VS Code Break Points - Can I add breakpoint every x number of executions?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I see that I can add a breakpoint condition to trigger after x executions, but I'm wondering if I can add a condition to trigger after *ever* x executions? I.e., I want to break every 10 times a certain function is triggered.

Is there a way to do that without manually editing the breakpoint each time it hits?

The closest thing I was able to find was this Issue on GH which didn't seem to provide an answer. Looks more like it's saying Xamarin has the functionality and VS Code doesn't. Am I reading this right?

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/issues/37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, you just have to do %x, which will break every x times the line is executed.

So I did %10, which stopped on the 10th execution, and every 10 thereafter.